# Permission denied : While setting classpath to run testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

Friends I am trying to run the testng.xml on my Linux environment , Getting below issues , I have given root access still not working.

```
[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite ]# sudo java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)


bash: allJarFiles/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar: Permission denied
[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite]# ls -ltr
total 230324
drwxrwxrwx 6 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jul 25 13:52 bin

drwxrwxrwx 2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jul 25 13:52 utility

drwxrwxrwx 7 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jul 25 13:52 src

drwxrwxrwx 2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jul 25 14:44 allJarFiles

-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins     1178 Jul 25 14:44 testng.xml

-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins      144 Jul 25 14:44 bash.sh

drwxrwxrwx 2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jul 26 07:14 inputFiles

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite ]# set classpath= /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebSite/bin;

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite ]# set classpath= /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/allJarFiles/*;

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite]# java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite  ]# sudo java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite  ]# set classpath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/allJarFiles/*;

[root@ip-Ec2-serverebsite ]# set classpath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bin;

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite ]# java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite ]# set classpath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bin;/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/allJarFiles/*;

bash: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/allJarFiles/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar: Permission denied
[root@ip-Ec2-serverwebsite ]#
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting a local variable classpath, but you are not specifying it on the java command.

Answer (score -1):

Try to grant apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and other lib jar files "execute" permission.

Comment: i gave all the permission to all the jar files .. it is giving all erros in the code line of jar file and 
PK: No such file or directory and 

 bqX: command not found /allJarFiles/jxl.jar: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('